# Display date like member for : "1 year, 10 months"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using `Angularjs` and would like to know how can I display a date in this "format"

member for : `1 year, 10 months`

Is there a `Javascript/Jquery/Angularjs` built-in function that is doing it or should I calculate it myself.

Thank you

Comment: There isn't a JavaScript or jQuery built-in function (I don't know Angular) for this, so yes, you should calculate it yourself.

Comment: -1 for "I didn't try anything yet since I'm waiting for any answer from you."

Comment: @DA. Why not.. but if I asked this question is to know If I had to calculate it myself so if the answer was yes I would do it. There is no logic to try to calculate it my self then ask the question after to know if there is some tools that already exist to do it. Not reinventing the wheel.. So your down vote has no sense for me. But for sure down-voting take less time as providing a good answer..

Comment: There is some logic in doing some research up front, though. For example, in the matter of seconds I found this via Google: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date It appears to be a rather comprehensive list of date formatting options in Angular. But to help you, jQuery tends to have a dozen plug-ins for most any need. I'd suggest googling "jQuery date formatting plugin" and see if something there will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't find exactly what I was looking for I did it myself.

So this function returns the time passed between two dates.

```
Date.prototype.from = function(pastDate, presentDate){

    var presentDate = (typeof presentDate === "undefined") ? this : presentDate;

    //the string to return.
    var dateString = "";

    var minute = 60 * 1000,
        hour = minute * 60,
        day = hour * 24,
        month = day * 30,
        year = month * 12,
        ms = Math.abs(presentDate - pastDate);

    var years = parseInt(ms / year, 10);
    ms -= years * year;

    var months = parseInt(ms / month, 10);
    ms -= months * month;

    var days = parseInt(ms / day, 10);
    ms -= days * day;

    var hours = parseInt(ms / hour, 10);
    ms -= hours * hour;

    var minutes = parseInt(ms / minute, 10);

     if(months <= 0 && days <= 0 && hours <= 0 && minutes <= 0){
        dateString = "1 minute";
        return dateString;
     }

     if(years > 0){

        if(years == 1){
            dateString += years + " year";
        }else{
            dateString += years + " years";
        }

        if(months > 0){

            if(months == 1){
                dateString += ", " + months + " month";
            }else{
                dateString += ", " + months + " months";
            }

        }
     //year = 0
     }else{
         if(months > 0){

            if(months == 1){
                dateString += months + " month";
            }else{
                dateString += months + " months";
            }

            if(days > 0){

                if(days == 1){
                    dateString  += ", " + days + " day";
                }else{
                    dateString  += ", " + days + " days";
                }
            }

         //month = 0
         }else{
            if(days > 0){

                if(days == 1){
                    dateString += days + " day";
                }else{
                    dateString += days + " days";
                }

                if(hours > 0){

                    if(hours == 1){
                        dateString += ", " + hours + " hour";
                    }else{
                        dateString += ", " + hours + " hours";
                    }

                }
            //days = 0
            }else{
                if(hours > 0){

                    if(hours == 1){
                        dateString += hours + " hour";
                    }else{
                        dateString += hours + " hours";
                    }
                    if(minutes > 0){

                        if(minutes == 1){
                            dateString += minutes + " minute";
                        }else{
                            dateString +=", " + minutes + " minutes";
                        }
                    }
                //hours = 0
                }else{
                    if(minutes > 0){

                        if(minutes == 1){
                            dateString += minutes + " minute";
                        }else{
                            dateString += minutes + " minutes";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         }
     }

    return dateString
}
```

**USAGE**

```
// now
var now = new Date();

var d1 = new Date("October 13, 1995 11:13:00")
var d2 = new Date("March 13, 2005 11:13:00")

// from now
alert( now.from( d1 ) )

// time elapsed between two dates 
alert( now.from( d1, d2 ) )
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/73sTz/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own filter which wraps `.fromNow()` in [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

```
filter('timeago', function() {
    return function(datetime) {
        return moment(datetime).fromNow();
    };
})
```

Then you can use it like any other angular filter;

```
{{ "2014-01-01T12:00:00" | timeago }}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gGFj/)

Comment: That's nice, but is there a way to display 3 years, 2 month, 8 days, 23 minutes ago ?